# How to iterate over rows in a dataframe between two values in one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, like this:

```
Underlying  Expiry  Strike  Right   Bid Price   Ask Price   Mid Price   Close Price
0   AAPL    20210115    18.75   P   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   AAPL    20210115    18.75   C   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   AAPL    20210115    20.00   P   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   AAPL    20210115    20.00   C   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   AAPL    20210115    21.25   P   NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   AAPL    20210115    21.25   C   NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   AAPL    20210115    22.50   P   NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   AAPL    20210115    22.50   C   NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   AAPL    20210115    23.75   P   NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   AAPL    20210115    23.75   C   NaN NaN NaN NaN
10  AAPL    20210115    25.00   P   NaN NaN NaN NaN
11  AAPL    20210115    25.00   C   NaN NaN NaN NaN
...
```

How can I loop over only the rows where df['Strike'] is between two numbers, e.g between 20 and 25?

Comment: `df[df.Strike.between(20,25)].iterrows()`

Answer (score 1):

You can select the rows where the strike is between two numbers by using

```
df[df['Strike'].between(20, 25)]
```